# readmore if giving the opposite response to what I expect

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `readmore` javascript in my program and it runs, but the answer is not correct.

When I click on "see more" it gives less output and when i click on "less" it is 'see more'. ie it is showing the opposite of what it should be.

I tried changing the code but it doesn't work properly.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 50; // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";

    $('.more').each(function() {
      var content = $(this).html();

      if(content.length > showChar) {
        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
        $(this).html(html);
      }
    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
      }

      $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
      $(this).prev().toggle();

      return false;
    });
  });
  </script>
  <title>jQuery Read More/Less Toggle Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="more">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit dolore magna aliqua.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat anim id est laborum.
  </span>
  <br><br>
  <div class="more">
    Morbi placerat imperdiet arcu massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst.  <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the title to give a shorter explanation of what the problem is that you're seeing - removing the sentence-structure and turning it into a simple bullet-point. I updated the grammar of the post to be better English (it's ok... you're doing great just being able to ask so well!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put wrong text to your anchor in `.morelink` `click` handler. You need to change it like below:

```
$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    }
    // rest of code here
}
```

And to display correct label in the beginning, you also have to change the html content you create on document load (`moretext` to `lesstext`):

```
var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + lesstext + '</a></span>';
```

Then it will behave in the way you want, but to cut text correctly, you will have to change your code a bit more.

Comment: thank you for replay .where use this var html . ? i place your jacascript code in my program it's not work sir

Comment: it's  work but now it shows first show less then show more

Comment: @Bhavesh `var html = ...` you need to put instead of the same line of your code. You have it in the line 12 of your inline javascript code. I put your modified example to jsFiddle - take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z7ztv6ua/). Also, please take your time to understand what does each line of code in your application means, because without the understanding of basics you won't be able to move forward.